# Link for CSS.php?

Tags: php, css, isset

So lately I've realized I want to make my sites as simple as possible in certain ways, one of them is having as few files as possible. I've looked into linking for CSS-PHP files using query strings, similar to how XenForo does it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.php?css=xenforo,form,public">
```

Now linking for a file is easy, but how would I add the CSS inside a PHP file without using the style tag? Can I just do something like the block below?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['form'])) {
?>
CSS HERE
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Echo file_get_contents('your_css_file.css');

Comment: The answer below was the correct one, and I'm trying NOT to use .css, but .php.

Comment: Ok, but you don't need to add separate headers.  You can still do `echo file_get_contents('your_css_file.css');` inside your `isset` function. Keep all css in a separate file anyway and load them in your PHP file when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<?php
header(Content-type: text/css");
?>
```

to the top of your php stylesheet.
eg:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
?>
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.php">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I combined this with my isset method, and it worked flawlessly, thanks!